# The Sequel gem qualified query column name with table double underscores

Tags: ruby, sequel

Using the Sequel gem:

```
employees = DB[:prm_master__employee.identifier]
.join(:prm_master__employee_custom_fields.identifier, :employee => :employee)
.where("termination_date >= ?","06/01/2012")
.or("termination_date = NULL")
.and("employee = 'holderl'")
```

The above fails with:

```
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.41.0/lib/sequel/adapters/tinytds.rb:221:in `fields': TinyTds::Error: Ambiguous column name 'employee'. (Sequel::DatabaseError)
```

I understand the error (same column names between joined tables, e.g employee), but do not know how I can qualify the employee condition in the `and` statement since the table uses the identifier method to ignore the underscores.

Comment: FYI: You're using three backticks as an attempt to mark a block of code. That doesn't work right. Use four spaces to indent instead. See the [Advanced Markdown documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information.

Comment: Github markdown is far superior. the four space indent is impossible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is to actually qualify the column name using:

```
Sequel.qualify(:table, :column)
```

Or the equivalent shorter syntax:

```
Sequel[:table][:column]
```

resulting in:

```
employees = DB[:prm_master__employee.identifier]
.join(:prm_master__employee_custom_fields.identifier, :employee => :employee)
.where("termination_date >= ?","06/01/2012")
.or("termination_date = NULL")
.and(Sequel.qualify(:prm_master__employee_custom_fields.identifier, :employee)  => "holderl")
```

Comment: This can also be used on model relationships to avoid ambiguity in `JOIN`s.

Comment: There's also the shorter syntax `Sequel[:table][:column]` (added it to the answer)

Answer (score 0):

User alias. OR put table_name.column_name

Comment: yes i understand that, but how to do that in sequel gem when double underscore cannot be used? see my answer.